# MariaDB specify maximum lock time when using LOCK TABLE

Tags: mariadb

I had assumed that using the following query:

```
LOCK TABLE LIST_SUBYACENTES WRITE WAIT 5;
```

Would lock the table for a maximum of 5 seconds, in case `UNLOCK TABLES` has not been called in that time.

Nevertheless, after Mysql Error 1205 "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction on insert" appeared, I checked the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/wait-and-nowait/) again and it seems that the amount of time specified with `WAIT` statement is the time before aborting the attempty to query the database if the table has been locked for all that time by another user.

What I wanted instead, is to make sure that, in case of any failure, the lock itself didn't last for more than 5 seconds, by getting the lock automatically removed after that time. Nevertheless, now I don't have a clue of how to achieve that. Any hint?

Comment: Mysql does not have wait clause for lock tables, therefore the question is not applicable to mysql at all.

Comment: Maybe that's why MariaDB is stated both in the title and the labels. MySQL is only in labels as it is probably compatible for what I am asking for (once that it is clear that WAIT statement is not a suitable solution for my problem)